# Create a Window with System.CodeDom.Compiler in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a Window in WPF while the application is running. WHY? Its part of my modell driven design.
It is not the window only. I want to load a XAML file and the window class behind the XAML.
What i know is how to create a simple class with System.CodeDom.Compiler. But on a window i need the "MyWindow.i.g.cs" file, the "class MyWindow : Window" and my XAML file.
What i want? I want set up databindings on the dynamic window in the constructor.

A little bit information behind my project:
I got a generator that generates code and xaml files from a modell.
I got a Database that is holding the c# code and xaml file in combination for each Window.
Now i got an application that load the windows by names from the database, compile and show it.
My Problem here is the declaration of my xaml Member (this.txt_Maintype). The compiler says "this is no member of Mainwindow".

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        TypeClass content;
        content = new TypeClass();
        this.DataContext = content;
        this.txt_Maintype.DataContext = content.Property_ident_deklaration;
        this.txt_template.DataContext = content.Property_ident_deklaration;
        this.txt_Extentiontype.DataContext = content.Property_ident_deklaration;
    }
}
```

And the Method  InitializeComponent() is not defined. I know there is an *.i.g.cs file in visual studio that implements the InitializeComponent. So how to merge all these files to compile it?

Thanks for help

I hope you understand what i want. It is difficult to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you are trying to do is possible. You need to use the Microsoft Build Engine (MSBuild) or Visual Studio to be able to build a WPF application that contains XAML markup.

This is stated in the documentation on MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/building-a-wpf-application-wpf.

> A WPF application can be compiled in the following ways:
>
> -Command-line. The application must contain only code (no XAML) and an application definition file. For more information, see Command-line Building With csc.exe or Building from the Command Line (Visual Basic).
>
> -Microsoft Build Engine (MSBuild). In addition to the code and XAML files, the application must contain an MSBuild project file. For more information, see "MSBuild".
>
> -Visual Studio. Visual Studio is an integrated development environment that compiles WPF applications with MSBuild and includes a visual designer for creating UI. For more information, see Application Development in Visual Studio and WPF Designer.

You could load a XAML string dynamically using the [XamlReader.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc663033(v=vs.110).aspx) method though.